# Create a GUI for Application

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, splash-screen

I have to create a program that starts with a splash screen and a transparent image, but in windows form not working there always the white background, how can I do?

Comment: What have you tried, how are you trying, what do you think you need to do? A splash screen is just a borderless window with an image and maybe progress bar that loads quickly and displays while the rest of the program starts up. Is this a homework assignment, or is it in an actual program? What language are you using, what technologies besides WinForms?

Comment: simple program for load a slpash screen without borderless, use the c# or other language with visual studio ultimate 2010. (trial)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a transparency key. If you set it to white, it will make everything that's white on the form transparent (doesn't work well with the picturebox control though).
So for instance, you create a panel, and give it the background image you want to be displayed, then set the transparency key to whatever color should be made transparent ;p

Comment: is possibility in WPF? always leaves the corners white and doesn't round as the image

Comment: @jolly You tagged the question winforms.  If you are trying to do this in WPF, then you should edit your tags accordingly.